# singular (some sound/ some noise) or plural (some sounds/some noises)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have made up the sentences below.

(1a) Sometimes, I hear some beautiful sound my neighbor makes with his computer software.

(1b) Sometimes, I hear some beautiful sound**s** my neighbor makes with his computer software.

(2a) When I got into my house, I heard some strange noise from upstairs.

(2b) When I got into my house, I heard some strange noise**s** from upstairs.

I am not sure which form of the nouns is correct. Please help me. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: We would say _some noises_ (plural), but _a noise_ (singular). It depends on whether you mean one kind of sound or several different ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a doesn't really make much sense at all.

1b makes complete sense, that is correct.

2a *could* be correct? It may not be grammatically correct, but I think it could pass as understandable if you were to say it.

2b makes complete sense as well, and it is correct. Out of 2a and 2b, use this one.